# Remove Windows FCI completely

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, clustering, failover, windows-server

When I built the cluster I forgot to uncheck the storage. It's now giving me all sorts of errors. How can completely remove the cluster so I can rebuild it? 
This is a 3 node cluster and I evicted two nodes, but when I try to evict the last node I get:

[image]

I removed all the Disk and Pools from the remaining node. 
Can you please guide me

Answer (score 1):

In Failover Cluster Manager, right-click on the cluster, select More Actions, and click on Destroy Cluster.

Comment: Thanks,I destroyed the cluster using the Destroy Cluster option but the virtual network name is still in AD